# Do something when text is completely removed from an input

Tags: javascript, input

I am trying to create an input that can be cleared with another input, but the clear button must hide when the text is removed/erased with backspace/delete key.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/FzVhW/

Any way I can do that?

HTML:

```
  <form action="#" id="cse-search-box" METHOD="GET">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="q" id="q" value="some value" size="35" autocomplete="off" onfocus="if (this.value == '') { document.getElementById('search_form_input_clear').style.background='#FFFFFF' };" onkeydown=" document.getElementById('search_form_input_clear').style.background='#000000'">

      <input id="search_form_input_clear" class="search_form_input_clear" type="button" value="X" OnClick="document.getElementById('q').value=''; document.getElementById('q').focus();" style="background: #FFFFFF; border: none; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF;">
      <input type="submit" value="Search" class="submit" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
  var clearbut = document.getElementById('search_form_input_clear');
  var searchfield = document.getElementById('q');
  if (searchfield.value != '') {
      clearbut.style.background='#000000'; 
  }
  else if (searchfield.value === '') {
      clearbut.style.background='#FFFFFF'; 
  }
```

Comment: Inlining multi-line JavaScript and cramming it into an `onclick` attribute is a bad idea. Use event listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this keyup instead of keydown function you use

```
onkeyup="if (this.value == '') { document.getElementById('search_form_input_clear').style.background='#FFFFFF' };"
```

in the element

It will work

Answer (score 1):

Add a listener to `onkeyup`. When ever a key release happens, a function is called where you check the input field value. If its empty, hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: Add an event listener to `onchange`. Check the value in the listener. If it's empty, hide the button.